# Unit testing a method that calls a method on newly created instance?

Tags: spring-boot, junit4, powermockito

We need to write junit test for below method.

```
public void Logout(){
  new SecurityContextLogoutHandler.logout();
}
```

How can we test where securitycontextLogoutHandler.logout method is called?
We are able to verify that a new instance of securitycontextLogoutHandler is created by usinf PowerMockito but not able to verify logout method call.

Below is the Test written:

```
SecurityContextLogoutHandler securityContextLogoutHandler = 
PowerMockito.mock(SecurityContextLogoutHandler.class);

PowerMockito.verifyNew(SecurityContextLogoutHandler.class);
```

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I would turn it around. Why do you create a new SecurityContextLogoutHandler explicitly when you can use dependency injection? If you inject the instance or a factory for the instance the code becomes easy to test.

Comment: Why are you even doing this? Looks like you are overriding the default spring security logout functionality which you shouldn't be doing in the first place.